# Stanford POS tagger in Java

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I'm trying this:

```
Sentence<TaggedWord> taggedString = MaxentTagger.tagStringTokenized("here is a string to tag");
```

which gives me:

> Error:
>   \u\nlp\data\pos-tagger\wsj3t0-18-left3words\left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger (The system cannot find the path
>   specified)

I'm using Stanford's [POS tagger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging).

What can I do to overcome this problem?

Comment: Download the full package of Stanford tagger, there you will find models, e.g., left3words...tagger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you first have to instantiate a tagger passing the included file:

```
new MaxentTagger("models/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger");
```

Which is pretty nasty as the tagging method used later is static:

```
MaxentTagger.tagStringTokenized("here is a string to tag");
```

I also had to pass `-Xmx256m` to make it run with that setup.

Comment: Yeah, it was pretty nasty, but that has been fixed now :-).  Version 3 has a pretty clean API!  You should now be good with MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(args[0]); String ans = tagger.tagString("Here is a string to tag.");

Answer (score 2):

It's saying that it can't find that path.  So, does it exist on your machine?

Note that the slashes are backslashes - does your OS support backslash as a file separator?

Also note that it's an absolute path - is that intended?

If all else is OK, does the file exist?

Edit:  if not, you should download it here (http://github.com/tiendung/ruby-nlp/blob/master/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger), place it in the path that the system is specifying, and see what happens.

Comment: it doesnt exist but i don't know where i'm supposed to get it from. i downloaded this:http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml so i assumed all the files would be included :S